# The positive ～じゃない

Tags: words, gender, feminine-speech

Just how feminine is it? How odd would it be if a male speaker said it? I have found one example of someone male using, in a piece of fiction: Lest レスト、 the main character of Rune Factory 4 ルーンファクトリー４、 at one point shouts 違ったじゃない　regarding something, and his speech patterns aren't that feminine (though not as masculine as they could be) - but I have a feeling that the game's script is nearly identical regardless of gender.

Comment: +1 because ルーンファクトリー４

Comment: I would argue it being not particularly feminine is basically dependant on who is speaking. Regardless of being Tokyo, or anywhere else, if spoken with female voice it will sound feminine. If spoken in a male voice, it will sound masculine. Examples that work are too numerous to list, but for example. A: 彼女めちゃかわいいじゃない？ B:いや、そうじゃないと思うよ。Without a female voice speaking, this could just be two guys having a chat about a girl. Alternately, it could be two girls talking about a girl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

～じゃない is not particularly feminine in Standard/Tokyo Japanese, as long as the ない is relatively short (i.e. sticks to the moraic rhythm) and maintains its low pitch.

I would say that the longer ない is drawn out, and the more rising pitch it is given, the more feminine it sounds.